# Criterion: Is it possible to alter Benchark graph?

Tags: haskell, haskell-criterion

I just started using the excellent `criterion` package and I was wondering if it's possible to alter the graph. For example I would need to

- normalize result within a group so that the longest result of a group take the full width of the graph (whatever the time spent in other groups)
- to change the order of the bars in the graph to be able to have a standard bar charts where instead of having cluster of bar of the same colours, you could have
  cluster of bars using all the different colours.

Comment: I know Carter Schonwald has done some work on such, and I think his report template may be [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cartazio/c3fa2513d733b4576e62). You could try asking on the haskell-cafe mailing list; he will likely respond.

Comment: I does the trick for the first question. It's good to know that the answer is in the template